# Does expl3 give a better strategy for this?

Tags: expl3

Right now, I’m defining a specialized float environment with

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{sidebar}{ O{\fps@sidebar} }
   {\edef\reserved@a{\noexpand\@xfloat{sidebar}[#1]}\reserved@a 
     % OTHER STUFF
   }
   {\end@float}
```

I’m thinking that this is precisely the sort of thing that all the fancy expl3 syntax is meant to simplify, isn’t it? If so, is there a “better”

**Updated to add** `\@xfloat` is a LaTeX kernel command (for those who don't have the kernel memorized). The above code is actually similar to how `\@float` is defined to handle the default case of no optional argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a simple `x`-type case

```
\use:x { \exp_not:N \@xfloat { sidebar } [ #1 ] }
```

Ideally you'd make `\@xfloat` protected, which is more a job for `etoolbox`

```latex
\robustify\@xfloat
```

to avoid the `\exp_not:N` too.

Comment: To clarify, `\@xfloat` is a LaTeX kernel command.

Answer (score 5):

You can make your own version of `\@xfloat` noting that it *requires* a second argument in brackets.

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \donhosek_xfloat:nn { \@xfloat{#1}[#2] }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \donhosek_xfloat:nn { nV }
```

and your `\fps@sidebar` should actually be a token list variable

```
\tl_new:Nn \donhosek_sidebar_default_tl
```

so you can now do

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{sidebar}{o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {% no optional argument supplied, use the default
    \donhosek_xfloat:nV { sidebar } \donhosek_sidebar_default_tl
   }
   {% optional argument supplied
    \donhosek_xfloat:nn { sidebar } { #1 }
   }
 }
 { \end@float }
```

If you *need* to use `\fps@sidebar`, then you can assimilate it to a token list variable and the code would be

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \donhosek_xfloat:nn { \@xfloat{#1}[#2] }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \donhosek_xfloat:nn { nV }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{sidebar}{o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {% no optional argument supplied, use the default
    \donhosek_xfloat:nV { sidebar } \fps@sidebar
   }
   {% optional argument supplied
    \donhosek_xfloat:nn { sidebar } { #1 }
   }
 }
 { \end@float }
```

In case the kernel changes how the optional argument is managed, you can modify the definition of `\donhosek_xfloat:nn` to take care of this.